# Any D7 modules similar to the Project Issues module?

Tags: 7

Are there any D7 modules similar to the [Project issues](https://drupal.org/project/project_issue) module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [7.x-2.x branch](http://drupalcode.org/project/project_issue.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-2.x) of the module in git.